# Try to use GET and POST, but this error keep using up, Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0, working on react

Tags: reactjs, post, get, fetch

[Trying to get data from db.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68rs0.png)

```
enter code here
```

Any help will be nice please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Instead of image write code chapters here ,that people can use it for debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to add 2 headers `Content-Type` and `Accept` equal to `application/json`.**

```
headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
}
```

**This will work for you.**

Comment: Thank you, but in what line or file i will need to add this.

Comment: You need to add this after `method: "POST",`

Comment: If you give me your Instagram id so it will easy for me to help.